# Xcode: How to find which storyboard controller includes an UITableView object

Tags: ios, xcode

I have to change a bottom constrain for all UITableView objects created via view controllers defined in a project storyboards. Project has many storyboards and a storyboard can have many custom controllers. Search result for IBOutlet var tableView is not exhaustive due to not all storyboard controllers has custom classes and not all storyboard controllers with custom classes have an IBOutlet.

Does Xcode has an Find feature which can work for my case?

**Update:**
I would like to list file names with path only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do it in Xcode, but from the shell it's not too hard to search every storyboard:

```
find . -name '*.storyboard' -exec grep '<tableView ' {} +
```

Edit: If you just want the file names:

```
find . -name '*.storyboard' -exec grep --silent '<tableView ' {} ';' -print
```

Comment: I found that command grep -r -l "<tableView " . filename print the same list. I don't know which one is more performing